# How to extract the first position of each day in sequence data

Tags: matlab, label

I have irregular sequence data as：

```
2019/1/1 3:00:00, 1
2019/1/1 4:00:00, 2
2019/1/2 3:00:00, 3
2019/1/2 5:00:00, 4
2019/1/2 6:00:00, 5
2019/1/2 7:00:00, 6
2019/1/3 2:00:00, 7
2019/1/3 3:00:00, 8
2019/1/3 4:00:00, 9
2019/1/4 3:00:00, 10
2019/1/4 4:00:00, 11
2019/1/5 1:00:00, 12
2019/1/5 3:00:00, 13
```

and I want to extract the first position of each day

```
   position   label
          1    1/1
          3    1/2
          7    1/3
         10    1/4
         12    1/5
```

Comment: What is that data exactly: a cell array, a table, a char 2D array...? How do you plot the data? Please post the relevant code

Comment: thanks for your reply
yes, I mean I want to set them
but the following are my expected result
   position   label
              1    1/1
              3    1/2
              7    1/3
             10    1/4
             12    1/5 
In fact, I just want to find the first position of each day in my example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not already the case, you need to convert your data to a `datetime` array. If you have a cell array of chars containing your data then you can use `data = datetime(data,'InputFormat',fmt)`, where `fmt` is the correct format for your dates.

Then you can use `dateshift` and `unique` to get the indices

```
% Shift the datetime array 'data' to midnight of the corresponding days
dates = dateshift( data, 'start', 'day' )
% Get the indices of the first instance of each day
[uDates,idx] = unique(data);
```

---

The full example using the data in your question would be something like this:

```
data = {'2019/1/1 3:00:00'
        '2019/1/1 4:00:00'
        '2019/1/2 3:00:00'
        '2019/1/2 5:00:00'
        '2019/1/2 6:00:00'
        '2019/1/2 7:00:00'
        '2019/1/3 2:00:00'
        '2019/1/3 3:00:00'
        '2019/1/3 4:00:00'
        '2019/1/4 3:00:00'
        '2019/1/4 4:00:00'
        '2019/1/5 1:00:00'
        '2019/1/5 3:00:00'};

data = datetime( data, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss' ); % Convert to datetime
data = dateshift( data, 'start', 'day' );                    % Shift to start of day
[uDates,idx] = unique(data);                                 % Get indices and values

%% Output:
% uDates = [01-Jan-2019; 02-Jan-2019; 03-Jan-2019; 04-Jan-2019; 05-Jan-2019]
% idx = [1; 3; 7; 10; 12]
```